# Tkinter - button command and gui blocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, tkinter

I'm trying to begin using tkinter for designing some graphical interface, but I actually have a problem...

Here is my little code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


# imports
from premier import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from time import *


# init var
varstop=False


# functions
def launch():
    """search first numbers between 2 and var entry"""
    listbox.delete(0, "end") # clear listbox
    itime=time() # init time
    n=entry.get() # get limit

    if n.isnumeric()==False or int(n)<2:
        # check inputs
        messagebox.showwarning("", "insert an integer (>=2) on the entry")  
    else:
        stop_button["state"]="normal"
        launch_button["state"]="disabled"

        n=int(n)
        i=2
        nb=0 # count number of first numbers
        varprogress=0 # var of the progress bar
        global varstop

        while i<=n:
            if varstop==True:
                # if click on stop button, stop
                varstop=False
                return
            else:
                if premier(i)==True:
                    nb+=1
                    listbox.insert("end", " "+str(i))
                varprogress=int((i*100/n)-varprogress+1)
                progress.step(varprogress)
                i+=1

        listbox.insert("end", " number of first number between 1 and "+str(n)+": "+str(nb))
        temp=time()-itime
        listbox.insert("end", " process time: "+str(int(temp))+"s")
        stop_button["state"]="disabled"
        launch_button["state"]="normal"

def stop():
    global varstop
    varstop=True


# define gui
gui=Tk()
gui.title("Premier.py")

frame1=Frame(gui)
frame2=Frame(gui)
frame3=Frame(gui)

label=Label(frame1, text="Limit (>=2) :")
listbox=Listbox(frame2, height=25, width=50, selectmode="extended")
progress=ttk.Progressbar(frame3, length=350)
entry=Entry(frame1, width=25)
launch_button=Button(frame3, width=10, text="launch", command=launch)
stop_button=Button(frame3, width=10, text="stop", state="disabled")

# create gui
frame1.pack(expand=True)
frame2.pack(expand=True)
frame3.pack(expand=True)

label.pack(side="left")
entry.pack(side="right")
listbox.pack(side="left")
progress.pack(pady=5)
launch_button.pack(side="left", padx=50, pady=5)
stop_button.pack(side="right", padx=50, pady=5)

gui.mainloop()
```

When I click on the launch button, the GUI just freeze until the end of the "while" of the launch function and I don't know why.
So, I'm unable to manage my progressbar for example...

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQgmIHkmHQM&feature=youtu.be) is a little video...

Do you know why the GUI freeze like that or how I can solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tkinter -> program freezing durint the execution of a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847626/tkinter-program-freezing-durint-the-execution-of-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

The "why" is because Tkinter is single threaded. When an event triggers a callback, that callback must complete before any more events can be processed.

To avoid this, you must:

1. move your time-intensive code to another thread, or
2. move your time-intensive code to another process, or
3. refactor your time-intensive code into small pieces that can be done in small iterations via the event loop, or
4. as an inefficient and possibly dangerous work-around, call `update_idletasks` after every iteration of your loop, which will at least allow "idle" events to be processed (such as redrawing the GUI)

Comment: What do you think to be the easier option ?

Comment: But you seem to say it's a little risky, and more, it unable user interaction... So, what is the easier way between 1,2 and 3 ?