# Why does tkinter.Tk.update() block while the window is being resized?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently working with `curio` and am trying to convert `tkinter`'s callbacks into something compatible with asynchronous code. I have most of the things figured out, the event waiting, protocols, but the only thing left is the window updating.

The `tkinter.Tk.update` method blocks while the window is resized. This screws my asynchronous code as everything must run without blocking. I can't run this in another thread, as [this answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10848959).

Here is some test code that will time how long the call to `update()` takes.

```
import tkinter
from time import monotonic

window = tkinter.Tk()
try:
    while True:
        started = monotonic()
        window.update() # This is the blocking call
        delta = monotonic() - started
        if delta >= 0.5:
            print(f'{func.__name__} took {delta} seconds to run')

except tkinter.TclError:
    # The window is closed
    pass
```

You can try resizing the window for a second, and the print function runs. If you leave it, nothing happens. This means that the event loop is always processing events from the resizing.

Note: Moving your mouse across the screen won't trigger it, event though with a little modification to check for events, the `<Motion>` events happen **way** more than the `<Configure>` events.

I can currently bypass this issue by running `tkinter.Tk.resizable(False, False)` to prevent resizing. I'd very much like to work without this restriction, and I am interested as to why the call blocks. Perhaps there are events being processed internally by the event loop, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does tkinter.Tk.update() block while the window is being resized?

I think the answer is because `update` must process all of the events in the event queue before it returns, and resizing a window sends a steady stream of events to the event queue as you drag an edge or corner of the window.

Comment: Could there be a way to get those events individually without blocking the loop? If not, I'll just keep it non resizable. Thanks :D

Comment: @GeeTransit: no, there is not.